# Continuity of a complex function - continuous arg?

Tags: complex-analysis

I will explain my misunderstanding with an example. Say I have a function $f:D\to \mathbb{C}$, with  $$D=\mathbb{C}\backslash\left\{ \left(1+i\right)t\,\,\,:\,\,\,-1\leq t\leq1\right\} $$ I don't see how any $f$ can be continuous, I can always find a circle of values in $D$ such that there is a discontinuity in the $Arg$ function. What am I missing here? I see everywhere that it is possible to construct a continuous function with domains like the one I provided.

*excluding a constant function, is it possible for $f(z) = z$ for example?

Comment: Constant  functions are continuous on any space aren't they?

Comment: You're right, but I'm talking about "more interesting" cases, for example $f(z) = z$. I will edit.

Comment: Any continuous function on $\mathbb C$ is also continuous on $D$.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding how you could doubt that $f(z)=z$ defines a continuous function. I also cannot see any connection between the continuity of $f$ and the non-continuity of arg.

Comment: For some reason I thought the discontinuity of arg makes $f$ also discontinuous, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that you define $\operatorname{arg}z$ as the only argument of $z$ such that $\operatorname{arg}z\in (-\pi,\pi]$. Then $\operatorname{arg}$ is indeed discontinuous at the points of $(-\infty,0]$. And we have $z=|z|e^{i\operatorname{arg}z}$. However , the discontinuity of $\operatorname{arg}$ at, say, $-1$ doesn't make $z$ discontinuous there, since, when $z$ is close to $-1$, then $\operatorname{arg}z$ is close to either $-\pi$ or to $\pi$ and, in both cases, $e^{i\operatorname{arg}z}$ is close to $-1$.

Comment: Thank you, that was my misunderstanding. Sorry for my poor question (I see I'm getting downvoted), I'm just starting at it.